# Firebase Hosting - 404 index.html - want to point to index.js instead

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting

I'm trying to deploy a basic diet.js single page app to firebase. Everything is deploying, though when I visit the page in the browser is says 404 there is no index.html file.

My projects entry point is index.js. My issue is that I guess I don't have the right configuration to point to the right place. This is my configuration.

The app is structured with an index.js at the base root. then views are in public/views/html with index.html there.

```
"target": "<project target>",
      "public": "/",
      "ignore": [
        "firebase.json",
        "**/node_modules/**"
      ],
      "rewrites": [
        {
          "source": "./**",
          "destination": "index.js"
        }
      ]
```

I'm missing something here I'm sure. Any help would be great!

Best,
Kieran

Answer (score 0):

You need to rewrite to an `index.html` file which then loads and executes the JavaScript. Otherwise users will just see the contents of the JS file when they navigate to the site.